# MyBatis and Nested Where Clause

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I have a strange problem and I'm not entirely sure where it lies. I have a simple nested where clause as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE 
(      e_start_date_and_time >= '2014-09-11 20:16:00.0' 
   AND e_end_date_and_time <= '2014-09-12 20:16:00.0'
) 
AND 
( 
       e_name LIKE "Some message" 
    OR e_description LIKE "Some message" 
    OR e_location LIKE "Some message" 
)
```

When I run this query in mysql workbench I get 2 rows returned. But when I put this query in a mybatis mapper file no rows are returned. I have ruled out something in my code by turning on java.sql debugging and putting a breakpoint just before the selectList method. The output i get is as follows:

> 2014-10-26 18:21:20,420 | DEBUG | [java.sql.Connection] | ==>
> Preparing: SELECT * FROM events WHERE ( e_start_date_and_time >= ? AND e_end_date_and_time <= > ? ) AND ( e_name LIKE ? OR e_description LIKE ? OR e_location LIKE ? )   2014-10-26 ?
> 18:21:20,726 | DEBUG |
>
> [java.sql.PreparedStatement] | ==> Parameters: 2014-09-11 20:16:00.0(Timestamp), 2014-09-12
> 20:16:00.0(Timestamp), "Some message"(String), "Some message"(String), "Some message"(String)

Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Can you try to use `'Some message'` instead of `"Some message"`?

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 e_name LIKE '%Some message%' 
    OR e_description LIKE '%Some message%' 
    OR e_location LIKE '%Some message%'
```